# $E\to X\to Y$ is an equalizer iff the given square is a pullback

Tags: proof-verification, category-theory

From Leinster:

[image]

I think both statements are true. Am I right?

For example, let's prove the converse. Suppose $h:A\to X$ is an arrow s.t. $fh=fg$. We need to show that there is a unique $\bar h:A\to E$ s.t. $i\bar h=h$. But this last claim holds because the given square is a pullback.

The other implication is proved in the same way but we just use the assumption that the diagram $E\to X\to Y$ is an equalizer instead of the assumption that the square is a pullback.

This looks quite easy, so I wanted to make sure I'm not missing anything.

Comment: I will think about this carefully later, but are you sure about the second implication? Note that here you start with *two* arrows $h_1,h_2$ so that $gh_1 = fh_2$ and you want to show they uniquely factorize via $i$. However, the hypotehsis of $i$ being an equalizer will only prove this when $h_1 = h_2$. Sounds like this allows us to produce a counterexample.

Comment: For example, if $X = \{ 0, 1 \}$ and $Y = \{ 0 \}$ with $f,g$ being the unique maps (in the category of sets) then what's the pullback of $f$ and $g$?  In this case, are the two maps from the pullback to $X$ equal?  Are they monomorphisms?

Comment: If $f=g$, then the equaliser is an isomorphism but the pullback is the kernel pair of $f$, whose projections are not isomorphisms (unless $f$ is a monomorphism).